# Is possible to enable Hyper-V using nested virtualization with Windows 7 as host?

Tags: windows, virtualization, docker, hyper-v

I'm tying to use docker on windows 10 virtual machine instaled on windows 7 host. I  manually enabled Hyper-V on VM, but when I try to start docker it return error

*The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: 'MobyLinuxVM' failed to start. ailed to start the virtual machine 'MobyLinuxVM' because one of the Hyper-V components is not running.*

As I understand it, VM still can't use Hyper-V. I know that is possible to enable Hyper-V on VM with nested virtualization, but I don't know if it is possible with not win10 as bare metal OS.

Comment: as you need a version of windows capable of running hyper-v (and win 7 does not) the answer has to be no.

Answer (score 2):

The following requirements must be met to implement nested virtualization in Hyper-V:

- The host operating system must be Windows Server 2016 or Windows 10 (Anniversary update or later). Older Windows versions don’t support nested virtualization.
- The Hyper-V VM must be of version 8 or higher.
- The physical server must have a compatible CPU that supports the appropriate virtualization features. Only Intel processors with VT-x and EPT technology support nested virtualization. AMD processors do not currently support nested virtualization.
- There must be enough physical memory to run the VMs.
- The VM cannot use Dynamic Memory.